# string with dash downcase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a very strange behaviour I cant't tell why this is happening.

```rb
"CWSDCTAX-1".downcase == "cwsdctax-1".downcase
=> false
```

```rb
(0..9).to_a.map{ |i| "cwsdctax–1".downcase[i] == "CWSDCTAX-1".downcase[i] }
=> [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true]
```

Why does this happen? I can't figure out why there is a difference?

Comment: If you run `"cwsdctax–1".codepoints` you'll see that the second to last character has a codepoint of 8211 (decimal) or 0x2013 (hex) which is [EN DASH](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm). (as opposed to 45 / 0x2D for [HYPHEN-MINUS](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002d/index.htm) for the other string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check the Unicode value for both `-`, it might be the case that even though it looks similar it has a different Unicode.

Refer to this link to check different dashed and hypes https://jkorpela.fi/dashes.html

```
[29] pry(main)> '-'.bytes
=> [45]
[30] pry(main)> '-'.bytes
=> [45]
[31] pry(main)> '‐'.bytes
=> [226, 128, 144]
[32] pry(main)> '-' == '‐'
=> false
[33] pry(main)>
```

Comment: I see thank you. There are differences. But what is the best solution to compare those strings?

Comment: Archer: please clarify your comment above, what you mean by both "There are differences." and "...best solution to compare those strings?".